# how to use the groupBy() function of collections

Tags: grails

I have some data returned in a query that include userid, name, week, days and project_count.
i.e.:

```
userid, name, week, days  project_count
14,     kirk,  1,    4.75
14,     kirk,  2,    3
14,     kirk,  3,    5
```

etc for each week of the year

The data is the time booked (day)  by each user per week

I’m trying to use the groupby so it will group this information by the name and add week and days to that group
i.e.:

```
[14, kirk[1,4.74],[2,3],[3,5]]
```

I will then use this data to create a table that will display the information. listed by user and week

#### Name Wk1   Wk2   Wk3   Wk4   Wk5    Wk6   Wk7

#### Kirk   4.75     3      5

The id is not displayed , i just thought it would help to group the data.
the project_count field will be used when generating the table to highlight the background of cells if the value is greater than 1. i tried to post an image to give a better idea of what Im doing but i do not have enough of a reputation yet.

[image: picture]

Comment: You might make some edits to give people a better understanding of what you want, e.g. remove the project_count bit, since it's not used, and maybe say what the numbers underneath Wk1 Wk2 in the output actually MEAN (they seem to be the days for each week, but the formatting is screwing it up?).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it so (without groupBy):

```
def groupped = data.inject( [:].withDefault{ [] } ){ res, record ->
  //         id         name               week           days
  res[ [ record[ 0 ], record[ 1 ] ] ] << [ record[ 2 ], record[ 3 ] ]
  res
}
```

at the output you should get:

```
[
  [ 14, kirk ]:[ [1,4.74],[2,3],[3,5] ] 
]
```

Comment: thanks for the quick replay but that seems to give me the same grouping as the select statement did

Comment: your code to iterate the grouped map doesn't make sense at all. it's indeed better if you describe what you want clearly and omit the irrelevant details. for example, the sql-ops have nothing to do with the grouping you are at

Comment: thanks, i will try the inject.  Is there documentation on this that i could read ? its hard to decipher this line when your new to Grails.

Comment: Hi again, so i tried the code, it returns the data as you said it would except that instead of creating a new 'row' for each new user it simply adds it to the end.  it also repeats this line constantly.\

Comment: like so:
[[ 14, kirk ]:[ [1,4.74],[2,3],[3,5] ],[15,Picard]:[1,3],[2,5],[3,2.25],[4,1,5]] ][[ 14, kirk ]:[ [1,4.74],[2,3],[3,5] ],[15,Picard]:[1,3],[2,5],[3,2.25],[4,1.5]] ]
[[ 14, kirk ]:[ [1,4.74],[2,3],[3,5] ],[15,Picard]:[1,3],[2,5],[3,2.25],[4,1.5]]]
i was looking for
[[ 14, kirk ]:[ [1,4.74],[2,3],[3,5] ]]
[15,Picard]:[1,3],[2,5],[3,2.25],[4,1.5]] 
[17,Sisko]:[1,1],[2,4.25],[3,4],[4,3]]]

Comment: you must be doing something else. I just ran the code in the groovy console, and it returns what I stated, no repetitions or whatever

Comment: I just copied and pasted the code and change data to row.  Maybe its in the manner i print. doing this just to see the data

userMap.each{
    println userMap
}

Comment: so, you are printing exactly the same map several times :)
you should use `userMap.each{ println it }`

Comment: thank you so much.  Hope i figure this out soon.  Still looking for the documentation. Now to figure out how to access it in a gspthanks again